# Automatically detect all map navigation applications installed

Tags: ios, swift, directions, turn-by-turn

In iOS apple maps application, when selecting a destination, apple maps gives you options to use any of the installed mapping apps to get turn by turn directions.

How does apple maps do this? is there a way to implement similar feature in my own app?

One way is to get a list of most popular navigation apps, check that they support url schemes, and check if any of them are installed by using:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        // mapping app is installed ...
}
```

However, this is not reliable as url schemes might change and also some of the mapping turn-by-turn apps do not support url schemes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Is this what you're looking for?</s>

Whoops, probably not what you were looking for, but this is how Apple Maps does it. Maybe somewhere in that documentation (or digging deep into it) you might find a way.

From Apple's docs:

> iOS apps that are able to display point-to-point directions can register as routing apps and make those directions available to Maps and other apps.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW9